# How to manipulate animate's duration with step function while animation is on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to change jQuery animate's duration with step function while animation is on, like easing effects. I created an example to inspect it, [**here is jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D7YbP/5/).

```
$('span').click(function() {
   var _this = $(this);
   if( !_this.is(':animated') ) {

       var target = 400;
       var speed = 1000;

        _this.animate({'top': target +'px'},{
            duration: speed,
            step: function(now,fx) {
                //what does fx stands for anyway, i cound'nt solve it?

                if ( now >= 300 ) { speed=100; }
                //condition works but it won't effect the current animation
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: The speed has already been passed as a parameter to the function, so I don't think changing the variable will work. If it's an easing you're trying to create, why not use $.extend() and the usual ways of making a custom easing. Do a search and you'll probably find a how-to on easings.

Comment: well, you're changing the speed variable, while you should be changing the duration variable

Comment: @adeneo I am trying to learn `step()` function and its limits but thank you for your advice, i'll search easing too.

Comment: @EliteOctagon - duration is'nt really a variable, it's a key in an object that is passed as a parameter.